# my default animation is taking priority over my own animation

Tags: animation, roblox

I set my animation priority to action yet the default animation still overlaps and I cant seem to find anyone that knows
here is the code

```
local contentprovider = game:GetService("ContentProvider")

local animations = script:WaitForChild("Animations"):GetChildren()

warn("assetsLoading")

contentprovider:PreloadAsync(animations)

warn("assetsLoaded")

local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = plr.Character
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local anim1 = script.Animations:WaitForChild("Animation")
local anim2 = script.Animations:WaitForChild("Animation2")
local load = humanoid:LoadAnimation(anim1)
local load2 = humanoid:LoadAnimation(anim2)

local usi = game:GetService("UserInputService")

usi.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, IsTyping)
    if IsTyping then return end
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.N then
        load:Play()
        wait(1)
        load:Stop()
        load2:Play()
    end
end)
```

Comment: Heyo, care to share your code? It's hard to tell where your mistake is without it.

Comment: yes I put the code in the description just now

Comment: When you created the animation, did you make sure to select the highest animation priority?